# grant access to user on amazon RDS server

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

i need to grant all privileges for user master to the database '`mysql`'(i mean the database not the server) on amazon RDS
i am trying to use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* To 'master'@'aurora-wqeqwe-rdscluster-1jjch50tq2n3s.qrwerw-2.rds.amazon
aws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'm3vyrtywrsY026y';
```

Comment: I hope you didn't just post your master password to the internet! You might want to change that.

Comment: @BillKarwin the password and the URI are fake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't grant `SUPER` privilege on RDS, so you can't use the `ALL PRIVILEGES` shortcut.

Sorry, you must name the privileges you want to grant explicitly, even if it means listing *every* privilege except `SUPER`.

You also can't grant privileges you don't have. I'm not sure your user has privileges to the mysql database. You can find out what privileges you have with `SHOW GRANTS`.

Comment: https://devopslife.io/access-denied-when-using-grant-all-on-in-aws-rds-mysql/

This will also work

Comment: That's crazy. This has changed since I started using AWS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example is "master" any user or is it the name of your RDS Master User account?  For the latter take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck with the same problem a while ago ad came across with this solution `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '%'.* To 'master'@'aurora-wqeqwe-rdscluster-1jjch50tq2n3s.qrwerw-2.rds.amazon
aws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'm3vyrtywrsY026y';`
This worked for me.
for more information you can check the following link
http://www.fidian.com/problems-only-tyler-has/using-grant-all-with-amazons-mysql-rds

Comment: I had to surround the `%` by backticks for this to work.